# c# polymorphism property

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a simple question.
There is a base class Product.
And derived classes as Bracelet, Earring and Ring.
But ring class has an extra property.

How am I going to reach that size property and use it in a method in below code.

```
public class Product
{
    public int id;
    public string title;
}

public class Bracelet : Product
{

}

public class Earring : Product
{

}

public class Ring : Product
{
    public int size;
}

Product product;
if(category = 1) // this is a  Bracelet
{
    product = new Bracelet();
}
else if(category = 2) // this is a Earring
{
    product = new Earring();
}
else if(category = 3) // Wola, this is a ring
{
    product = new Ring();
    product.size = 4; // I cant reach size.. I need to assign size of the ring to decrease stock correctly.
}

product.decreaseStock();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare the value locally first:

```
else if (category == 3) 
{
    var ring = new Ring();
    ring.size = 4;
    product = ring;
}
```

This way, you have access to the variable as a `Ring` within your `if` block, but it also assigns it to the more general `product` variable too.

Alternatively, you can just use initializer syntax:

```
else if (category == 3) 
{
    product = new Ring { size = 4 };
}
```

Comment: Would be good to mention that you'll need to cast the `Product` to a `Ring` to access the `size` field when needing to read the value.

Comment: True, though if he's actually casting to retrieve the value, there's probably something wrong with the design.

Comment: (S)He who does not cast shall cast the first stone.

Answer (score 1):

Kirk Woll's answer is probably best, but an alternate solution would be to use the 'as' keyword:

```
(product as Ring).size = 4;
```

or to cast it:

```
((Ring)product).size = 4;
```

Also, make sure you don't confuse the assignment operator (=) with the equality operator (==). It should be, for example, if(category == 3)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to override the decreaseStock method in Ring.

So, in product, first mark the decrease stock method as virtual.

```
public class Product
{
    public int id;
    public string title;

    public virtual void DecreaseStock()
    {
        //your decrease logic here
    }
}
```

Then in ring, put your new logic that takes size into account in your override method

```
public class Ring : Product
{
    public int size;
    public override void DecreaseStock()
    {
        //your special logic to deal with size here
    }
}
```

Comment: Who saaid size had anything to do with decreasing stock?

Comment: @JonHanna Correct but it would be nicer if each object took care of its own properties, rather than `if, else if, else if`

Comment: Yes, when possible, but it isn't always.

Comment: The Author:How am I going to reach that size property and use it in a method in below code.

Comment: Right you are. The scrolling led me astray :(

Answer (score 0):

You better read Jeffrey Richter's CLR via C#.

You can't refer to `ring`'s property by `product` reference, because CLR wouldn't know that this object is ring, and that's why CLR won't allow you to change it's size.
Instead you should use:

```
Ring ring = new Ring();
ring.size = 4;
```

If you want to reach this property via `product` reference it should be declared in base class.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since you are altering the size just after you've created the `Ring`, the way to go is to deal with it as a `Ring` rather than as a `Product`:

```
Ring ring = new Ring();
ring.size = 4;
product = ring;
```

In a case where we had a `Product` we knew was a `Ring` we could cast. This will cause a runtime error if it is in fact an `Earring`:

```
Ring ring = (Ring)product;
ring.size = 4;
```

Or more concisely:

```
((Ring)product).size = 4;
```

In cases where the product might be a `Ring` and might not, and we want to set  `size` if it is, we can of course test:

```
if(product is Ring)
  ((Ring)product).size = 4;
```

Often it's sensible to combine the test and cast:

```
Ring ring = product as Ring;
if(ring != null)
  ring.size = 4;
```

A lot of casting is a bad sign. Generally, we should be dealing with an object at the level we care about - only doing `Product` things when all we know is that it is a `Product`. One thing that can help do this is by accessing the method or property from an override:

```
public class Product
{
  /* leave out other stuff */
  public virtual bool NeedsLargeBox
  {
    get
    {
      return false; // most products don't
      //(this property could also be abstract to force all derived
      //classes to decide upon how it operates)
    }
  }
}

public class Ring : Product
{
  public int size;
  public virtual bool NeedsLargeBox
  {
    get
    {
      return size > 100;
    }
  }
}
```

Now while `Ring` itself deals with `size`, code could process a bunch of `Product` objects and decide how many needed large and how many small boxes, without that code having to access `size` directly (or even know about it, it could be written and working before `Ring` was even created).